# Magento - Add field to related product

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

I'm looking for a alternative where I can have a second field beside 'position' in the 'related products' tab (@ product creation).

This field must be of decimal type and should be stored in the database. At this moment:

I've changed this file `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\data\catalog_setup\data-install-1.6.0.0.php` by adding this at line ~175:

> ```
> ...
> array(
>   'link_type_id'                  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED,
>   'product_link_attribute_code'   => 'extra_field',
>   'data_type'                     => 'decimal'
> ),
> ...
> ```

And this piece of code have created a new field in the 'link' in the database. And added a new column here `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Related.php` (line ~216) :

```
    $this->addColumn('extra_field', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
            'name'              => 'extra_field',
            'index'             => 'extra_field',
            'width'             => 60,
            'editable'          => !$this->_getProduct()->getRelatedReadonly(),
            'edit_only'         => !$this->_getProduct()->getId(),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'           => $options
    ));
```

And add the following line (around 122) in the file `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\catalog.xml`:

```
            <action method="addColumnInputName">
                <input_name>position</input_name>
                <input_name>extra_field</input_name> <!--This one-->
            </action
```

At this moment, I'm able to store/retrieve this new information correctly. There's only one last problem: when I click in the dropdown, the whole line gets disabled (the checkbox in the beginning is unchecked).

Why is it happening? It became really annoying.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inchoo's post was a really good starting point (as usual):
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/

This another poster may be also helpfull somehow:
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/

To solve the problem follow the steps described in the question.

To solve the UI problem, use the method described in the following thread:
[Magento select field disables row in related products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381179/magento-select-field-disables-row-in-related-products)

Everything's working for me now :)